# JSF Passing a POJO through Session

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

So I have a bean

```
public class MyBean
{
private List<MyClassObject> myList;
//getters and setters
}
```

The the class MyClassObject has inside it another list

```
public class MyClassObject
{
 private List<MySubClassObject>mysubList;
 //getters and setters
}
```

then I have a JSF Page

```
<p:dataTable id="xyz" var="Class" value="#{MyBean.myList}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                MyClassObjects
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Prop1">
                <h:outputText value="#{Class.prop1}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Prop2">
                <h:outputText value="#{Class.prop2}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Prop3">
                <h:outputText value="#{Class.Prop4}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Sub Classes">
                <p:commandButton value="Open Sub Class" url="/faces/pages/SomeOtherPage.xhtml"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Now the objective here is that I want to create a button/commandButton or anything to click that will navigate to another page and display another similar table of the MySubClassObject List found in that particular rows var.

**Is there a way to pass the var="Class" to the url destination so it can be accessed by the next table (this is the required logic I know the answer for that exact execution flow is no, what I am looking for is how to achieve the same functionality properly) ?**

Thank you very much !

Comment: I apologize ahead if there are syntax errors as definitely this is not my naming convention and the original bean is a very very large application scoped one which will make it very difficult to follow on the required logic here

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like:

```
 <p:commandButton value="Open Sub Class"
    action="#{MyBean.selectClass(Class)} />
```

Inside your 'MyBean' you had to write something like:

```
public String selectClass(MyClassObject obj){
    this.selectedObj = obj;
    return "/faces/pages/SomeOtherPage.xhtml"
}
```

Here, you can access "var=Class" through **#{MyBean.selectedObj}**.

One important thing here is the scope of MyBean. Good look.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response, but how can I make selectClass(MyClassObject obj) session scoped. That would work well for a single session, but if multiple sessions navigating to different SubClassObjects tables this is going to trigger problems and opening wrong objects

Comment: Hi @a.atlam It's not clear to me. The session is unique by user and various users using the same user case, each user will have your own session. If "MyBean" is session scoped solve your problem no?

Comment: Hi@Lucas Oliveira Well actually thats not possible. MyBean is Application scoped as it holds data sources constantly feeding. The point is, once a user selects the data sources he wants, from the main MyBean, the redirection should point to that source. The problem will arise if a second user chooses a different source and first one refreshes the page. it will load the wrong object. Thanks a lot though you gave me some inspiration ... will try something and let you know